# Compiz plugin (Grid) does not update in CCSM

Tags: unity, compiz, plugins, 13.10

I upgraded to 13.10. Compiz itself has been updated properly to 0.9.10.2, but in CCSM, one* plugin ([Grid](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid)) shows up as the old version. I know it has been changed and *I can actually see the updated version when I log in with another user*. This hints of some kind of a problem with per-user settings?

(* Actually I'd expect this to involve other if not all other plugins too, but I have simply not yet noticed others.)

So far I have tried:

- resetting Compiz settings to defaults (GUI-way) does not help
- completely removing & reinstalling `compizconfig-settings-manager` and `compiz-plugins` packages does not help

In 13.04, I had a patched/old version of the plugin, but I doubt it is about that since everything is fine with the other user (that user account existed already in 13.04).

What configuration files I should try deleting?

Answer (score 1):

**Found solution**

I backupped all CCSM settings by exporting the configuration file (including the default values):

**`CCSM` ⇒ `Preferences` ⇒ `Export`**

Then I deleted the following folders:

```
~/.cache/compizconfig-1
~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1
~/.config/compiz
~/.config/compiz-1
~/.compiz
~/.compiz-1
```

Not sure which of those did the trick, but just in case I decided to remove all of them - I've retained those since 12.10 anyway...

Restarted Unity/Compiz via the terminal:

```
unity
```

Then imported the backup of the settings. Now the Grid plugin is working properly.